# Magento 1.9 base table or view not found - MW One step checkout

Tags: magento-1.9, sql, onestepcheckout

In Magento 1.9.3 I've installed MW One step checkout, everything is working fine, but one thing: atfer login to magento panel -> sales -> orders, I've got error:

```
a:5:{i:0;s:416:"SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'db231214.mw_onestepcheckout' doesn't exist, query was: SELECT `main_table`.*, `one_step`.`mw_deliverydate_date`, `one_step`.`mw_customercomment_info`, `one_step`.`mw_deliverydate_time` FROM `sales_flat_order_grid` AS `main_table` 
LEFT JOIN `mw_onestepcheckout` AS `one_step` ON one_step.sales_order_id=main_table.entity_id ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT 20";i:1;s:4925:"#0 /magento-2/lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array) [...]
```

I tried to make sql query, but I with no luck (I'm not so close with sql).

Comment: Is it possible that the installation script didn't run correctly for the module? You should be able to remove the entry in the core_resource table for the extension then flush cache to re-run it.

Comment: did you find solution

Comment: thanks for all comments, solution from @abhinav-singh is working with additional steps - as below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is a common issue when you are installing any extension in magento. This error occurs when your modules tables are not created in the database.

Please do following steps to resolve this issue.

1- Please disable cache.

2- Now open your database and search table name "core/resource". And find an entry for "mw_onestepcheckout". Please delete this row entry and run the site again in the browser.

3- Now you will see your setup is created again and new row entry will be created.

4-Same time your all modules tables will be created. 
Hope this will help you.

Comment: Thank you!, with your advice it works. Only one more step I had to do - get rid of /app/code/local/Onestepcheckout extension and add it again to start installation again. Thanks a lot!